# Long Netty Server Debug Message virtually hangs Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, netty

While I use a proxy based on Netty, Netty writes out all the debug messages to the log. Since I download/upload images, Netty is that smart to print the content of a 10MB image to the console as part of the "value" property of the response object.

The problem: Eclipse isnt that well when it comes to handling console lines being 10 million characters in width :(.

Is there anything I can configure to make netty smart enough to only print lets say the first 1000 chars?

Comment: limitting console output from eclipse's preferences may help u. window > preferences > run/debug > console > ...

Comment: Dont think so. The problem is that the console output would be not fitting a single such line. But basically the console would be rendered useless since I would loss the past every time nettiy is going to record an upload / download

Comment: Find Netty's logging config. From what I read it uses SLF4J, so it can have logback as a logging implementation. You can use "Format modifiers" in logback to truncate too long messages.

Comment: are you using LogHandler? netty doesn't log every request unless you configure it to do so.